# Get high resolution profie picture urls for all contact with one request. Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can get high resolution with `/id/picture?type=large&redirect=false&width=400&height=400` but using this syntax I need to make a connection for each user which is not really what I want. Can I do it with one go? `/me/friends?fields=id,name,picture` is not an option because it gives you links for low res pictures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it should work:

```
$facebook->api(me/friends?fields=id,name,picture.type(large));
```

Comment: Yes this is what I wanted. Any chance to make it even higher resolution? This is 180x180 and I need 250x250.

Comment: you should try this: `me/friends?fields=id,name,picture.height(250).width(250).type(large)`

Comment: Interesting. Whatever resolution I provide it is always 320x320. Anyways I rather downsize than upsize. Thanks!

Comment: oh.. I think since facebook does not keep all size pictures so they return the picture of closest matching dimension from whatever is available with them.